# Programmatically create new routes in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I am using a json file pulled from the server to configure my website, and to tell each page what it's title is. The json file looks like this:

```
[{"route": "student", "title": "Student Info Page"}, {"route": "payments", "title": "Payments and Pricing"}, {"route": "policy", "title": "Mine"}, {"route": "biography", "title": "About Me"}]
```

which is used to create a navigation bar with this code:

```
App.MenuController = Ember.ArrayController.create();
$.get('config.json', function(data) {
    App.MenuController.set('content', data);
});
```

which is then used in the template:

```
{{#each App.MenuController}}
    {{#varLink route this}}{{title}}{{/varLink}}
{{/each}}
```

All of this works great so far.

So here's my question: I want the route mapping done with `App.Router.map` to be done programatically, using this json object to determine which routes should exist.

How on earth should I do this? I've hunted around the documentation, and then tried this:

```
$.get('config.json', function(data) {
    App.MenuController.set('content', data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        App.Router.map(function(){
            var r = data[i].route;
            console.log(r);
            this.route(r);
        });
    }
});
```

which gives the following console readout:

```
student app.js:9
payments app.js:9
policy app.js:9
biography app.js:9
Assertion failed: The attempt to linkTo route 'student' failed. The router did not find 'student' in its possible routes: 'index' ember.js:361
Uncaught Error: There is no route named student.index ember.js:23900
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used this to create the routes dynamically:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.MenuController = Ember.ArrayController.create();

App.deferReadiness();

simulateAjax(function(data) {
    App.MenuController.set("content", data);    
    App.Router.map(function() {
        var router = this;
        data.forEach(function(item) {
           router.route(item.route); 
        });
    });
    App.advanceReadiness();
});
```

`simulateAjax` is just a function that simulate an ajax call to the server.

`App.deferReadiness();` and `App.advanceReadiness();` delay the application startup, so you don't have the effect of the screen blink, because of the update of new added routes. Since our application ready is: when the routes are created, not document ready.

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/jDUy6/)

### UPDATE

`link-to` helper support dynamic routing, using a object and path.
But at the moment its needed to use `ENV.HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS = true`.

With this, we don't need to create a custom `linkTo` to handle dynamic path, like the first demo ;)

New [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/nV2gG/)

Comment: Nice approach, this renders my pessimistic answer obsolete :)

Comment: Sir, you are incredible.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the ember-cli?