# Interpret ember templates twice?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a template which loops through an array of all my navigation links. But I would like to use the ember linkTo helper for my links.

My template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="_sideNav">
    <div id="sideNav">  
        <ul>
        {{#each model.sideNav}}
        <li>{{link}}
            <a>
                <i {{bindAttr class="iconClass"}}></i><p>{{label}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

My model:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Overview",
        "iconClass": "icon-overview",
        "link": "{{#linkTo Overview}}Hello{{/linkTo}}"
    }, {
        "label": "Posts",
        "iconClass": "posts",
        "link": "{{#linkTo totalEnergy}}Hello{{/linkTo}}"
    }
]
```

You can see I have put linkTo helpers in my model, which doesn't really make sense, and of course I get the text "{{#linkTo totalEnergy}}Hello{{/linkTo}}" appearing on my page.

But I think you can see what I am trying to get at here, and I think it would be really helpful to be able to use templates to generate other templates. My actual navigation has 12+ links which change based on server data and what is relevant on the page.

I feel like I could hack this to make it work, by not initializing the ember app until some handlebars templates have been run, but Im wondering if anyone has a better idea.

Thanks

Comment: I think that is more simple return a metadata about your links, like: `links: [{ url: 'totalEnergy', label: 'Hello'}, ...]`. And then set in your templates using: `{{#linkTo url}} {{label}} {{/linkTo}}`. What do you think?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is more simple return a metadata about your links, like:

```
App.MenuController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        {"route": "student", "title": "Student Info Page"}, 
        {"route": "payments", "title": "Payments and Pricing"}, 
        {"route": "policy", "title": "Mine"}, 
        {"route": "biography", "title": "About Me"}
    ]
});
```

And then set in your templates using:

```
{{#each routeObject in App.MenuController}}
    {{#linkTo routeObject.route}}{{routeObject.title}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

But to enable the binding of the `linkTo` to some object. Is needed to set:

```
Ember.ENV = {
    HELPER_PARAM_LOOKUPS: true
}
```

Comment: Dont have time to try this now, but will do in a few hours. Seems legit.

Comment: I forget of this, thanks for remember. I you need dynamic routing, in that other question have a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062271/programmatically-create-new-routes-in-ember/18063916#18063916.

Answer (score 0):

You could make another template for links and use the 'render' helper to pass along the model for each link